# Accessing specific columns in Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python

I have the following csv file:

```
name,shortname,description,class,child.1,child.2,child.3, ... child.300
Audi AG, Audi,, vehicle,A3,A4,A5 ... Awhatever
.
.
.
Mercedes Benz, MB,, vehicle,C,A,B ... GLEwhatever
```

So, there are multiple rows and multiple columns.

I want to print per each row, only the child columns, something like this:

```
Audi: 
A3
A4
A5
...
Awhatever
.
.
.
Mercedes Benz:
C
A
B
...
GLEwhatever
```

So far I have tried by using `iloc` method in Python as follows but cannot get it work.

```
    cars = pd.read_csv("cars.csv")
    df = pd.DataFrame(cars)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        print(row[0], (df.iloc[1, 4:300]))
```

I checked some tutorials for `loc` and `iloc` but that's very complicated for me as a beginner, so is there any alternative to get the result I intend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways of doing this - depending on what exactly you'd like the output to look like:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    print(row[1][0]) 
    print(row[1][4:])
```

Output:

```
Audi AG
child.1    A3
child.2    A4
child.3    A5
Name: 0, dtype: object
Mercedes Benz
child.1    C
child.2    A
child.3    B
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Method 2:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    print(row[1][0]) 
    for c, v in row[1][4:].items():
        print(f"- {c}:{v}")
```

Output:

```
Audi AG
- child.1:A3
- child.2:A4
- child.3:A5
Mercedes Benz
- child.1:C
- child.2:A
- child.3:B
```

---

If each car has both a model and a color, you can do the following:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    print(row[1][0]) 
    items = list(row[1].items())
    for inx in range(4, len(row[1]), 2):
        car = items[inx]
        print(f"- {car[0]}: {car[1]}")
        color = items[inx+1]
        print(f"  - color: {color[1]}")
```

The output is:

```
Audi AG
- child.1: A3
  - color: red
- child.2: A4
  - color: blue
- child.3: A5
  - color: black
Mercedes Benz
- child.1: C
  - color: green
- child.2: A
  - color: yellow
- child.3: B
  - color: white
```

Comment: Thank you @Roy2012, exactly what i needed.

Comment: Sorry for botherin again @Roy2012 but if I do have `Audi AG, Audi,, vehicle,A3,blue,A4,red,A5,green ... Awhatever,anycolor` is there a way I can print 
`Audi AG
- child.1:A3 blue
- child.2:A4 red
- child.3:A5 green
`

Comment: Do you mean there are two columns for every car? As in one column for 'A4', and another one for 'blue'?

Comment: one column per car, followed by its color 
car,color
A4,blue

Comment: So for each car (i.e. 'child' in the original question), there are two columns: one column for A4, and another one for 'Blue'. Is that accurate?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.

Comment: See my latest edit. If that doesn't help, consider asking a new question, with a data sample, and mention me. I'll have a look.